# What exactly is a lattice? And can somebody give an example of something that is not one?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, order-theory

Looking at the (very brief) definition in my textbook with no examples, I have the following:

> A poset $(A,\preceq)$ in which every two elements have a greatest lower bound in $A$ and a least upper bound in $A$ is called a *lattice*.

But I can't think of a poset that **doesn't** have a GLB and LUB...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about this one? What’s the least upper bound of the two fellows at the top?

```
        *   *  
         \ /  
          *
```

Comment: $$\Huge\mathsf V$$

Comment: You could also mimic the infamous $\sf W$ directly, that would have worked equally well.

Comment: Thanks. Never considered this. This is why I need to study more :)

Comment: @agent154: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 7):

$$\Huge\ldots\vphantom{Some filler, if only there was a two-dots symbol}$$

Comment: Antichains forever!

Comment: Brian, so antichains are Strawberry Fields?

Comment: Well, I think that you could safely say that Lennon was anti-chains!

Answer (score 5):

I (and presumably William of Ockham) suggest a 2-element antichain.

Comment: That was my original answer, but I replaced it with the sleek and dazzling succinct answer "$\ldots$" (a three-element antichain).